# SQL Query combination

Tags: sql, join, plsql

I have following data on table `User`.

```
EMPID   FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    MANAGER     
---------------------------------------
10017   Pawan        Kumar        3448
3448    Anwar         Sadad       1088
1088    Anand           R         3525
```

I have 3 queries

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMPID='10017';  
SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,MANAGER FROM USERS WHERE EMPID='3448';   
SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME FROM USERS WHERE EMPID='1088';
```

Please help me combine these three query or a new query where I can select first and last name of the Manager of employ with empid 3448 who is the manager of 10017.

How can I select 1088 (Anand R) who is the Manager two level manager of 10017 (Pawan Kumar)

Comment: a hint use IN operator

Comment: Did you test anything before asking?

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting...?

Comment: Try to read on hierarchical queries, connect by prior

Answer (score 1):

answer to your question will be this quesry if i have got your question right

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME 
FROM USERS
WHERE EMPID=(SELECT MANAGER 
            FROM USERS 
            WHERE EMPID=(SELECT MANAGER 
                          FROM USERS 
                          WHERE EMPID='10017'));
```

if you want to select the manager and again manager of employee with empid 10017

Comment: Did you test something?

Comment: That'd be great except for the syntax and column name errors. Perhaps you could fix those up..?